# How do I fill a UITableView that is a subview of a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I need to create a view that contains a vertical stack view, which holds a Label, a TableView, another Label, and a Button (in descending order). I have been struggling trying to configure the TableView, as I cannot get it to fill with cells (currently just appears as a blank space in the super view). Right now, I have a ViewController for the main view - 'YourOrderViewController' - and a TableViewController for the TableView - 'OrderItemsTableViewController'. It looks like this:

The main view

```
class YourOrderViewController: UIViewController{

var cellTitle = String()
var cellSubtitle = String()

@IBOutlet weak var orderListTable: UITableView!

let orderTableController = OrderItemsTableViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    orderListTable.delegate = orderTableController
    orderListTable.dataSource = orderTableController
}
```

And the TableView subview

```
class OrderItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var drinkOrderList = [Drink]()
var foodOrderList = [Food]()

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if section == 0 {
        return drinkOrderList.count + foodOrderList.count + 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrderItemCell", for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.row < drinkOrderList.count {
        cell.textLabel?.text = drinkOrderList[indexPath.row].drinkName
    } else if indexPath.row - drinkOrderList.count < foodOrderList.count {
        cell.textLabel?.text = foodOrderList[indexPath.row].foodName
    } else {
        print("Also here")
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddToOrderCell", for: indexPath)
 }

 return cell

}
```

I initially tried making the whole thing in one view controller, a UIViewController that was the delegate and data source of the UITableView, but that did not work either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sorry i can't see where you add your OrderItemsTableViewController.view to your view hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Plain & simple you are over doing it.

For example:

```
orderListTable.delegate = orderTableController 
orderListTable.dataSource = orderTableController
```

`orderTableController` instance of `OrderItemsTableViewController` is a `controller` type, **instead it** should an NSObject type of class which conforms to tableView delegate & datasource.

```
class TableViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSouce {
     // no need of controller's life cycle
     // just declare all & implement all protocol required  
}
class TableViewDelegate: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
    // have some property where you could set the data after you initialize this object
}
```

Now you could do

```
let _delegate = TableViewDelegate()
let _dataSource = TableViewDataSource()  
_dataSource.someDataProperty = data //<-- important 
orderListTable.delegate = _delegate 
orderListTable.dataSource = _dataSource
```

Also, in you controller, you need to add method to `reload this tableView`

In your `cellForRowAt`, just use one custom cell for now until you got it working

Comment: Thank you! I was actually able to make the ViewController itself the delegate and data source, but this cleared it up for me to get there.